# extract parantheses of text with regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a text and I want to extract Parentheses of text with regex java.
for example of text:

```
<p>Now a days, regenerative medicine(1) in stem cell(3) filed
   widely <label>attractive(10) by</label> attractive by scientists(4).</p>
```

if Parentheses exist between label tags,I want to extract all text between label tags.
for example of extract above text:

```
(1)
(3)
<label>attractive(10) by</label>
(4)
```

Comment: And? You have tried what in Java so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
(?is)\(\d+\)|<label>.*?\(\d+\).*?</label>
```

#### Demo

http://regexr.com?37ktp